# What all characters can be used as String Delimiters in Java?

Tags: java, string, delimiter

I am trying break a String in various pieces using delimiter(":").

```
    String sepIds[]=ids.split(":");
```

It is working fine. But when I replace ":" with " * " and use " * " as delimiter, it doesn't work.

```
    String sepIds[]=ids.split("*"); //doesn't work
```

It just hangs up there, and doesn't execute further.

What mistake I am making here?

Comment: *,? and few other symbols have special meaning in regex (look it up).
You have to escape them "\\*" will work

Comment: String sepIds[]=ids.split("\\\*"); //works

Comment: possible duplicate of [java split function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257459/java-split-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.split` expects a regular expression argument. * has got a meaning in regex. So if you want to use them then you need to escape them like this:

```
String sepIds[]=ids.split("\\*");
```

Answer (score 2):

[String#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/literals.html) as parameter. In regex some chars have special meanings so they need to be escaped, for example:

```
"foo*bar".split("\\*")
```

the result will be as you expect:

```
[foo, bar]
```

You could also use the method [Pattern#quote](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) to simplify the task.

```
"foo*bar".split(Pattern.quote("*"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The argument of `.split()` is a regular expression, not a string literal. Therefore you need to escape `*` since it is a special regex character. Write:

```
ids.split("\\*");
```

This is how you would split agaisnt one or more spaces:

```
ids.split("\\s+");
```

Note that Guava has `Splitter` which is very, very fast and can split against literals:

```
Splitter.on('*').split(ids);
```

Answer (score 1):

'*' and '.' are special characters you have to blackshlash it.

`String sepIds[]=ids.split("\\*");`

To read more about java patterns please visit [that page.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 1):

That is expected behaviour.  The [documentation for the String split function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) says that the input string is treated as a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) (with a link explaining how that works).  As Germann points out, '*' is a special character in regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Java's `String.split()` uses regular expressions to split up the string (unlike similar functions in C# or python). `*` is a special character in regular expressions and you need to escape it with a `\` (backslash). So you should use instead:

```
String sepIds[]=ids.split("\\*");
```

You can find more information on regular expressions anywhere on the internet a quite complete list of special characters supported by java should be here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html